# Want to Retain the calling app's url in addressbar after redirecting

Tags: javascript, jsf, servlets, servlet-filters, spring-webflow

My project is in Java(Spring/JSF) and from our project we are calling .Net application.When we reached to .Net application, there we do some valid search and after that they just redirect(sendRedirect) the response to my application(Java application).

**One more thing we need some parameter from .Net application's response in our application.**

**My Application Local url**:http://localhost:8080/US

**DOT NET application url**:http://20.12.223.12/excess/

But problem is that when it come back to our application, our application url is changed to 
.NET application url "http://20.12.223.12/excess/".We just want to retain our application localhost url(requestUrl).

Is there any way to retain it?

Please give your suggestion!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please clarify. The user starts at your localhost:8080, you redirect them to 20.12.223.12, then want that .Net application to redirect them back to localhost? Or you send your own HTTP request to 20.12.223.12 from your server? A true HTTP redirect will always set the user's browser address to the redirected address.

Comment: Yes, we want to redirect back from .Net to localhost:8080 and it's happening. But problem is that when it come back to our application, our application url is changed to .NET application url "20.12.223.12/excess/".We just want to retain our application localhost url(localhost:8080/US).

Comment: So when the user first leaves the .NET application, they do see localhost:8080 in their URL bar, correct? But you're saying that the next submission from that page sends them to 20.12.223.12? I definitely don't understand what you mean by "our application URL is changed".

Comment: Sorry for confusion!

Initially when user redirect from localhost to .Net application, the addressbar url is change from localhost(http://localhost:8080/US) to .Net url(http://20.12.223.12/excess).It's fine.
And there after submission at .Net app.,it redirects back to calling app(localhost).

After returning back to calling app(http://localhost/US),the address bar still displaying the .net app url(http://20.12.223.12/excess).
It should display the localhost url.